# Pain in Rape vs. Seduction, isnt the difference obvious?

Tags: maseches-kesubos, knas-penalty, mefateh, tzaar

The gemara in Ketubot 39a and 39b discusses the difference between the pain endured during rape and seduction in order to fully understand why a rapist has to pay צער and a seducer doesn't. From the gemara and rishonim (i.e. תוס' ד"ה צער דמאי) we can see that the difficulty the gemara has in finding the difference is because ultimately all women have pain during their first intercourse.

Isn't the difference very simple and obvious, during rape a women is assaulted and is very often even physically injured, in other words, there is much physical pain involved when the intercourse in unconsented. If so, what at all is the gemara's discussion?

Comment: Any incidental physical wounds are not what this payment is about. These payments are about the sex itself. If he ties her up or beats her or something, he also pays for that like any other wound